# Empty / Null Nodes returned from getChildNodes

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I'm trying to parse the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docusign-cfg>
    <tagConfig>
        <tags>
            <approve>approve</approve>
            <checkbox>checkbox</checkbox>
            <company>company</company>
            <date>date</date>
            <decline>decline</decline>
            <email>email</email>
            <emailAddress>emailAddress</emailAddress>
            <envelopeID>envelopeID</envelopeID>
            <firstName>firstName</firstName>
            <lastName>lastName</lastName>
            <number>number</number>
            <ssn>ssn</ssn>
            <zip>zip</zip>
            <signHere>signHere</signHere>
            <checkbox>checkbox</checkbox>
            <initialHere>initialHere</initialHere>
            <dateSigned>dateSigned</dateSigned>
            <fullName>fullName</fullName>
        </tags>
    </tagConfig>
</docusign-cfg>
```

I want to read either the name or content of each tag in the `<tags>` tag. I can do so with the following code:

```
public String[] getAvailableTags() throws Exception
{

    String path = "/docusign-cfg/tagConfig/tags";
    XPathFactory f = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath x = f.newXPath();
    Object result = null;
    try 
    {
        XPathExpression expr = x.compile(path);
        result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } 
    catch (XPathExpressionException e) 
    {
        throw new Exception("An error ocurred while trying to retrieve the tags");
    }

    Node node = (Node) result;
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    String[] tags = new String[childNodes.getLength()];
    System.out.println(tags.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    {
        String content = childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");

        if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
                childNodes.item(i).getNodeName() != null)
        {
            tags[i] = content;
        }
    }

    return tags;
}
```

After some searching I found that parsing it this way causes it to read whitespace between nodes / tags causes those whitespaces to be read as children. In this case the whitespaces are considered children of `<tags>` .

My output:

```
37
null
approve
null
checkbox
null
company
null
date
null
decline
null
email
null
emailAddress
null
envelopeID
null
firstName
null
lastName
null
number
null
ssn
null
zip
null
signHere
null
checkbox
null
initialHere
null
dateSigned
null
fullName
null
```

37 is the number of nodes it found in `<tags>`
Everything below 37 is the content of the `tag` array.

How are these null elements being added to the `tag` array despite my checking for null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is because of the indexing of tag. The if check also skips an index. So even though value is not being inserted it will result in null. Use separate index for tag array

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
{
    String content = childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");

    if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
        childNodes.item(i).getNodeName() != null)
    {
        tags[j++] = content;
    }
}
```

Since you are omitting some of the child nodes, creating an array of entire child nodes length may result in wastage of memory. You can use a List instead. If you are particular about String array you can later convert this to an array as well.

```
public String[] getAvailableTags() throws Exception
{
    String path = "/docusign-cfg/tagConfig/tags";
    XPathFactory f = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath x = f.newXPath();
    Object result = null;
    try 
    {
        XPathExpression expr = x.compile(path);
        result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } 
    catch (XPathExpressionException e) 
    {
        throw new Exception("An error ocurred while trying to retrieve the tags");
    }

    Node node = (Node) result;
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    {
        String content = childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");

        if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
            childNodes.item(i).getNodeName() != null)
        {
            tags.add(content);
        }
    }

    String[] tagsArray = tags.toArray(new String[tags.size()]);
    return tagsArray;
}
```

Comment: Of course the `if` statement works and I just didn't realize that particular array index wasn't initialized because it was skipped.

I have no idea why I decided to use a regular array. I've since changed it to an ArrayList.

Comment: By default array will be null. No initialization happens. But you can fill an array with some default value if you want. Using `java.util.Arrays.fill()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of tag array defaults to null.

So it is not a case of how does the element become null, it is the case of it being left as null.

To prove this to yourself, add the following else block like this:

```
   if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
            childNodes.item(i).getNodeName() != null)
    {
        tags[i] = content;
    } else {
        tags[i] = "Foo Bar";
    }
```

You should now see 'Foo Bar' instead of null.

A better solution here would be to use an ArrayList, and append the tags to it instead of using an array.  Then you do not need to track the indexes and so less chance of this type of bug.